# Attiny85 - RSTDSBL fuse bit confusion

Tags: attiny85

Am I correct that to disable the reset pin of Attiny85, and use it as an IO pin, I need to disable the reset fuse bit(RSTDSBL)?

If so, should my RSTDSBL bit be 1 (assuming 1 = yes, disable)?

I am a little confused, because it looks like my reset pin got disabled only after I set the RSTDSBL bit to 0 (which is reverse of the logic I expected).

Comment: Please not that after programming the fuse you CAN NOT use an in-circuit programmer any more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AVR fuses use negative logic; 1 means the fuse is unprogrammed/unset, while 0 means it's programmed/set. Thus, if the documentation says to program RSTDISBL, that means you should set it to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now it makes all sense and can go to bed! (I wilt accept it as the answer in 8 min; apparently I can't accept it so soon).